# Need for the `builtin` builtin

Tags: bash, shell-builtin

What's the point of the `builtin` builtin when the `command` builtin has the exact same functionality when it comes to looking up builtins?

When making sure that a particular builtin is chosen over a function with the same name, `builtin` offers no additional value compared to `command`. One could argue that `builtin` is more explicit but still, I could only imagine that using `command` might be picked when one is not sure if some command is also available as a builtin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`builtin` is not a standard utility.

The POSIX standard documentation says this in [the Rationale section for the `command` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html#tag_20_22_18):

> The `command` utility is somewhat similar to the Eighth Edition shell `builtin` command, but since `command` also goes to the file system to search for utilities, the name `builtin` would not be intuitive.

The `builtin` utility is provided by `bash` for backward compatibility.

I note that `dash`, for example, does not implement `builtin`:

```
$ builtin printf 'hello\n'
/usr/local/bin/dash: 3: builtin: not found
```